How Google Sheets' new Conditional Notifications' alerts look like and why are they lost?
I realize it's a new service, but its single purpose in life is to send e-mail messages, so why am I not getting them? While the help center claims "Tip: Email notifications may not be immediate", even a day later I still got nothing.

It gives no option for anything but mail, but cares enough to reject Slack addresses as if they want to make sure it won't be used for Slack alerts...likewise, it rejects Google Group messages, always with the dreaded message of "Unable to send notifications to this email".
But even if I give a standard Gmail based addresses, I get no mail even a day later.

Can anyone at least mention what is the From address of these alerts and what is the Subject if it's a static one? That way I can ask an admin to try finding it in logs.
Also, rejecting Slack addresses is one thing, but Google Groups??
Update: another alert did arrive, as if it's random. Subject was "Important values changed in [filename]".


Works for me on about a 5-minute delay. Emails are sent from "Spreadsheet_owner_name" <sheets-automation-noreply@google.com>

It's so weird I've never got it. I'll ask admins to look in logs, but it should have just arrived.

in a managed environment they would be best placed to solve it.  May be an anti-abuse policy/custom mail routing rule(s) are discarding or bouncing the messages. Any bounces or replies are discarded by Google so there is no feedback mechanism.

The admins claim the alert that didn't arrive was completely missing from logs, while the alert that did arrive was logged as usual.

Hard to comment on that without knowing how the infrastructure is managed and whether or not the issue was actually on the org's side or Google's. If these notifications need to be relied on and you are finding them inconsistent, you may consider doing  it yourself via apps script and the Sheets and Gmail APIs

So I was running across this problem in our domain as well. However, I only had 2 users out of the 10-15 I tried that it wouldn't work on. After digging and digging I finally found out it blocks it if you don't enable "Email notifications from Google Drive" in the Notifications setting in Google Drive. Why that setting would block an entire email somehow is beyond me, but Google likes to do things weird sometimes.

Good catch if that's the issue! If it was 2 of 12-15 it is probably better characterized as a user disabling it as opposed to neglecting to enable it.

Do you mean Get all updates about Google Drive items via email (screenshot)? If so, I did have it enabled. Also updated the question that another alert did arrive to me, as if it's random.

Interesting. Yeah the "Get all updates about Google Drive items via email" is what I was referring to. At least on my end when I was having the sending error, enabling this prompt fixed the problem in our domain.
